# Removing .html and .php from links in IIS

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

As the title says, I would like to know how to remove ".html" and ".php" from links in a Windows server (IIS).

Most of the information I have found about this subject was only valid for Linux servers.

Only today I heard about the file `web.config` and got new material to study. Nevertheless, I am still struggling with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the url rewrite module for IIS: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Here is a good tutorial on the subject: http://www.surfingsuccess.com/asp/iis-url-rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already saw both links, but they don't look simple to me! :D I will check again though!

Answer (score -1):

Read about friendly-url and .htaccess

See an example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?pag=$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?pag=$1&id=$2 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

That way when you use:

> localhost/contact

The server will do an internal redirect to:

> localhost/index.php?pag=contact

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought .htaccess didn't work in a windows server. The code you mention should be put in web.config file?

Comment: Hi, I'm Brazilian too. :) No, you need create a .htacess file, and inside this file, write the code. Web.Config is for .NET websites.

Comment: @user3072304 This answer is about Apache. You can run Apache on Windows, but if you have a `web.config` file, you aren't running Apache, you're running IIS and serving pages with ASP.NET. To avoid answers that don't apply to you, mention the relevant information in your question: not just which operating system your server uses, but also which web server software!